# How can I add a text above my list in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, text

I am trying to display a list using a list title but would like to add a text with a click event to the top of the list.
How could I do it?

I would be very grateful for the help.
I am trying to display a list using a list title but would like to add a text with a click event to the top of the list.
How could I do it?

I would be very grateful for the help.

Code and image::

```
Widget StatefulBuilderSuggestions(BuildContext context ,List <SearchDelegateModel> historialMenuPrincipal){
    
        return Container(
          child:StatefulBuilder(
            builder:(context,setState)
        {
    
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: historialMenuPrincipal.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,i)
          {
           contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12,horizontal: 16);
            return  
          ListTile(
    
             subtitle: Text(historialMenuPrincipal[i] == null ? "no data" :historialMenuPrincipal[i].email,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ), 
                  title: Text(historialMenuPrincipal[i] == null ? "no data" :historialMenuPrincipal[i].contrasena,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
    
               trailing:  historialMenuPrincipal[i] != null || historialMenuPrincipal.isEmpty
                    ? IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.cancel,color: Colors.black,),
            onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
          historialMenuPrincipal.remove(historialMenuPrincipal[i]);
          });
          },): null
              );
          }
      ),
    
    );
        }
          )
        );
    
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use a column with 2 parts, title as a textbutton and above the list

```
Container(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    hideList = !hideList;
                  },
                  child: Text("Title"),
                ),
                hideList ? ListView() : Container(),
              ],
            ))
```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a Text widget  above a list, both widgets should be inside a column and important thing to note is that ListView widget must be inside a Expanded widget and for the text widget to be clickable, use `GestureDetector`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {}, child: const Text("Some text above the list")),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 50,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                      child: Text("$i"));
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did this help you?@Michael Antonio